# Upload file to Box.com (Android)

Tags: java, android, box

I've been following the example code on https://github.com/box/box-android-sdk/ as well as the documentation. However whenever I try to upload a file to box.com I receive the following error:

> 11-13 18:25:45.222 20996-21555/com.caa.capturebox W/System.err: com.box.androidsdk.content.BoxException: An error occurred while sending the request (401)
>   11-13 18:25:45.237 20996-21555/com.caa.capturebox W/System.err:     at com.box.androidsdk.content.requests.BoxRequestUpload.send(BoxRequestUpload.java:114)
>   11-13 18:25:45.238 20996-21555/com.caa.capturebox W/System.err:     at com.caa.capturebox.MainActivity$5.run(MainActivity.java:441)

Below is the last attempt I made however whether I try to upload from an input stream or from a local file I get the same error above.

```
    private void uploadFile() {
    mDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, getText(R.string.boxsdk_Please_wait), getText(R.string.boxsdk_Please_wait));
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Log.e("mya", "uploadFile: entered try");
                FileInputStream uploadStream = new FileInputStream(image_name);
                //InputStream uploadStream = getResources().getAssets().open(uploadFileName);
                String destinationFolderId = "0";
                String uploadName = "BoxSDKUpload.jpg";

                //BoxRequestsFile.UploadFile request = mFileApi.getUploadRequest(uploadStream, uploadName, destinationFolderId);
                BoxRequestsFile.UploadFile request = mFileApi.getUploadRequest(image_name, "0");
                final BoxFile uploadFileInfo = request.send();
                showToast("Uploaded " + uploadFileInfo.getName());
                loadRootFolder();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (BoxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                BoxError error = e.getAsBoxError();
                if (error != null && error.getStatus() == HttpStatus.SC_CONFLICT) {
                    ArrayList<BoxEntity> conflicts = error.getContextInfo().getConflicts();
                    if (conflicts != null && conflicts.size() == 1 && conflicts.get(0) instanceof BoxFile) {
                        //uploadNewVersion((BoxFile) conflicts.get(0));
                        return;
                    }
                }
                showToast("Upload failed");
            } finally {
                mDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since you have (401) response, I assume that it's Not Authorized http code returned. Have you been login to box : [box login documentation](https://github.com/box/box-android-sdk/blob/master/doc/Authentication.md)

Please login in order to use box services with this code:

```
BoxSession session = new BoxSession(context);
session.authenticate();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The first thing I do is authenticate and am able to confirm that I am logged in afterwards. However whenever I try to upload a file after authenticating I receive the error listed above.

Comment: did you get the API key & developer  token ? https://box-content.readme.io/docs/how-to-get-an-api-key With the developer token, you can run rest/http queries upon box services.

Comment: yes, when you launch the app for the first time it goes through the Box authentication process. Afterwards I am able to browse through files/folders however when I go to upload a local file or input stream it doesn't work and only throws the 401 response. I've made some changes to the code that I will test tonight and update but I fear it will be the same result.

Comment: if  your last test is not working provide code, I'll take a  look this weekend

Comment: I've uploaded my test code to [Github](https://github.com/subnetzero/CaptureBox) please be aware that the Client ID and Secret have been cleared out. Today I'm going to try running it through a proxy to see if I can get any more details on the 401 error.

Comment: So now I'm seeing a 403 error after some additional changes. `11-19 12:20:53.458 31916-32217/com.caa.capturebox W/System.err: com.box.androidsdk.content.BoxException: An error occurred while sending the request (403)
11-19 12:20:53.458 31916-32217/com.caa.capturebox W/System.err:     at com.box.androidsdk.content.requests.BoxRequestUpload.send(BoxRequestUpload.java:114)
11-19 12:20:53.458 31916-32217/com.caa.capturebox W/System.err:     at com.caa.capturebox.MainActivity$5.run(MainActivity.java:437)`